# Office 365 Group Calendar: Invite Group with categories

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the Graph API to create an event in a group calendar and I invite another group.

Group A creates Event E and invites Group B.

In the POST request, I will set categories which are correctly shown for Group A.

But using a GET request to get the meeting that arrived at Group B the categories are gone in the JSON response.

Yes, categories are not synchrnoized between groups, but I would assume that when sending a meeting request to a group, the categories should still get send?

Answer (score 0):

Please go ahead and raise a feature request to synchronize categories between groups here https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests so that the corresponding team can look into the possibility of picking it up for implementation in the future.